# set UIImageView to display middle section of an image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I've got an image view that I want to show a central slice of the user's profile picture. I want to scale the picture so that the width matches the width of the screen while maintaining the aspect ratio, center the image, and then have any extra on the top/bottom to not appear at all.

I've tried setting the imageView.contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, `UIViewContentModeCenter` and a few others, but it either resizes my UIImageView, changes the aspect ratio, or doesn't fill the area.

Comment: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill should do what you need.. What result do you get from it?

Answer (score 0):

> "but it either resizes my UIImageView"

I guess you see the cropped parts.
Maybe you forgot the "clipsToBounds" property?

```
UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: ___ ];
view1.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed:@" ___ "];
view1.image = img;
view1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```